# I am not getting records of 14 miles radius. Google Place API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using free service of Google Map and Google Place API. I want to fetch Google API places around me (my current location) and here i am setting radius is 14 miles but this is not returning 14 miles records. Either it is returning max 2 miles records or just 40-50 records from Google Place API.

Here is request code to call 14 miles radius records:

```
FTGooglePlacesAPINearbySearchRequest *request = [[FTGooglePlacesAPINearbySearchRequest alloc] initWithLocationCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(App_Context.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, App_Context.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)];
request.rankBy = FTGooglePlacesAPIRequestParamRankByDistance;
request.radius = 14 * 1.6 * 10000;
request.pageToken = currentPagingIndex;
switch (type) {
    case Bar:
        request.types = @[@"bar"];
        break;
    case Cafe:
        request.types = @[@"cafe"];
        break;
    case Florist:
        request.types = @[@"restaurant"];
        break;
    case Park:
        request.types = @[@"night_club"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

if (isCategoryselected) {
    request.types = @[[selectedPlaceCategory valueForKey:@"place_type"]];
} else {
    request.types = @[@"bar", @"cafe", @"restaurant", @"night_club"];
}


NSAssert(request, @"Provided request cannot be nil");
//    request.openNow = YES;


return request;
```

I am setting place type and page token properly. But i am getting page_token nil after 3-4 request max.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: I do believe google's api return 50 results by default, and gives you a next page token for you to call again if you need more results.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer thanks for reply.  It is giving 20 records in each batch so I have to repeatedly call this method for all 14 miles radius records. but i get page token nil after 3-4 requests.